# android Progress bar dismissed early

Tags: android, android-progressbar

my code:

```
OnClickListener()//onclicklistener for button
{
    ProgressBar = new ProgressDialog(LoginPageActivity.this);
    ProgressBar.setMessage("please wait..");     
    ProgressBar.show();

    TcpConnection loginConnect = new TcpConnection();//TcpConnection is a class
    loginConnect.run();
    ProgressBar.dismiss();
}
```

i tried to show progress dialog before calling another class and dismiss it after the call is over. but progressbar will not showing and it dismissed early . but i want to show progress bar for certain period of time.

Inside tcp connection class: having socket connection for user name password thats y i need to display progress for certain period of time

i dont know how to do it!

Comment: Your grammar is very unclear. What is the problem? ProgressBar not showing or showing too short?

Comment: You need some basic programming lectures :)

can you please post your code of TcpConnection class. basically you start the ProgressBar and after starting the thread you immediately dismiss the dialogue. you need to dismiss ProgressBar in you TcpConnection class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I understand you need to use threads. Like this

```
ProgressBar p = new ProgressDialog(LoginPageActivity.this);
Private Handler handler = new Handler();
p.setVisibality(0); //makes visible
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
                   public void run() {
                          TcpConnection loginConnect = new TcpConnection();
                          loginConnect.run();
                          handler.post(new Runnable() {
                                           public void run() {
                                      p.setVisibility(8);//Makes Invisible                      
                                                }
                                              });
                                   }

                  }).start();
```

I think it will help you

Comment: thanks for Big.child ,, i tried above method but at the last line there is option called StartActivity(Intent intent) instead of start() . what was wrong in my code

Comment: whoo i got the result superbly ,, again thanks to  Big.child and every one ,,, im verry happy now,,,

Answer (score 2):

Use `AsyncTask` to achieve your objective. You can show the `progressbar`(inside `onPreExecute()`) until your task gets over(inside `doInBackground()`) and then you can dismiss it after the task is finished(inside `onPostExecute()`).

Check this link for more details:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: ProgressBar not showing if i use ProgressBar.dismiss(); otherwise it is shown

Comment: What is `TcpConnection` class doing?

Comment: TcpConnection having Tcp socket connection to send data to server and get response from it. its works fine but the progress is the problem.

Comment: if i use AsyncTask the same problem continues,,

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that `loginConnect.run()` is running in its own thread. That's why the progress dialog is being dismissed instantly.

Here's what you should do instead:

```
class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog d;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        d = new ProgressDialog(LoginPageActivity.this);
        d.setMessage("please wait..");     
        d.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        TcpConnection loginConnect = new TcpConnection();
        loginConnect.run();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        d.dismiss();
    }   
}
```

And in your `onClickListener` call `new LoginTask().execute();`